# How can i fix the error coming from fs.outputJsonSync node.js

Tags: node.js, object, filesystems

I'm using node js to compile a smart contract.

I want to import from this smart contract two objects(represents two contracts) and store them in a file directory called "build" with a JSON extension.

When I run the command node compile.js, I got this error:

```
errno: -4058, syscall: 'open', code: 'ENOENT'.
```

When I've debugged my code, the error occurred from fs.outputJsonSync?

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const solc = require("solc");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");

fs.removeSync(buildPath);


const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Campaign.sol");


const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, "utf8");


const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;
console.log(output);

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

// To loop throught the contracts that contains 2 objects with data 
for (let contract in output) { 
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, contract + ".json"),
        output[contract] 
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error states that the file doesn't exist. The error comes in when you are  reading the file, make sure the file exist before you read it because  `fs.outputJsonSync` creates the file if it doesn't exist.

```
// Function call
// Using callback function
fs.outputJSON(file, {name: "David"}, err => {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  console.log("Object written to given JSON file");
});
```

Try to keep the `readFileSync` method in try/catch:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const solc = require("solc");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");

fs.removeSync(buildPath);

let output;
const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Campaign.sol");

try {
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, "utf8");
      output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;
console.log(output);
fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(`Error while reading the file ${e}`);
}


// To loop throught the contracts that contains 2 objects with data 
for (let contract in output) { 
   try {
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, contract + ".json"),
        output[contract] 
    );
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error while writing JSON: ${e}`);
   }
}
```

It is good to wrap different operations under different try/catch for error separation.

Comment: with the code that you shared, I got an error in this line that output is not defined => for (let a contract in output)? what do you think ?

Comment: You need to make it a global variable using let. Please check now. Make sure the file you are reading shoul be present. If the above code fails, it will give you the error in console.

Comment: Yeah exactly, it gave me an error and I didn't get the 2 JSON files inside the file "build" which is buildPath? What do you think I should do Chikara? the code that I wrote above was just from a tutorial it works in the tuto but it didn't work for me

Comment: Try creating those files before hand from the code. It might solve the problem.